# Definition of intersection multiplicity of a curve with some hyperplanes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm studying the chapter 2 of this [paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02568416?no-access=true) and I have the following doubt:

What is the definition of intersection multiplicity of a curve $C$ with some hyperplanes at a point $P$?

Remark: My only background is [Fulton's Algebraic curves book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf).

I really need help.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: There are several possible definitions. Maybe the simplest is this: near $P$ any hypersurface is defined as the zero-set of a holomorphic function $f$. Restrict $f$ to the curve $C$. Now if $z$ is a local coordinate on the curve $C$ near $P$ such that $z(P)=0$, we can write $f_{|C} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i z^i$. The intersection multiplicity is the smallest $i$ such that $a_i \neq 0$.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh in this context what is the definition of holomorphic function? I didn't see this definition in Fulton. Thank you.

Comment: Dear user42912, in this context "holomorphic" is interchangeable with "regular". Does that help?

Comment: Do you know where I can find this definition in a more formal way? thank you again

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know right now where this definition of intersection multiplicity is written down. Textbooks in algebraic geometry (e.g. Harris, Shafarevich) will discuss intersection multiplicity --- you could look in those to find other (equivalent) definitions.

Answer (score 0):

@user64687 gives an adequate description for many purposes.

Historically, the definition of intersection multiplicity has not been easy/straightforward.  Some of this history can be followed through André Weil's "Foundations of Algebraic Geometry" (1946) and William Fulton's "Intersection Theory" (1984).  I recall (but perhaps recall fuzzily) that Jean-Pierre Serre's "Algèbre locale, Multiplicités" (1965) definition via "Serre's Tor-formula" finally captured what was generally meant by the term entirely rigorously.  (Aha.  The Wikipedia article [Intersection Theory: Intersection multiplicities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_theory#Intersection_multiplicities) seems to agree, so I may be correctly remembering.  This section of this article has a version of this definition.  This section also has a diagram demonstrating a place where user64687's description is perhaps vastly more enlightening.)